# render a view from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, renderpartial

I'm trying to render one view (index) from one controller to the view of another controller.
index needs to calculate some values in the controller and render the view.

How do I do this?

example: in products/list I have

```
<%= render :partial=>"admin/index" %>
```

and in admin_controller:

```
def index
   @member = something
end
```

looks like the code in admin/controller never gets executed.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render will just render the view, it won't run the action associated with it.

You have to copy this:

```
   @member = something
```

to your products/list action.